# Elastic BeanStalk app deploy post hook not executing my command

Tags: amazon-web-services, continuous-integration, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, devops, continuous-deployment

I recently was able to get my Laravel app deployed using codepipeline on Elastic Beanstalk but ran into a problem. I noticed that my routes where failing because of php.conf Nginx configuration. I had to add a few lines of code to EB's nginx php.conf file to get it to work.

My problem now was that after every deployment, the instance of the application I modified the php.conf file was destroyed and recreated fresh. I wanted a way to dynamically update the file after every successful deployment. I had a version of the file I wanted versioned with my application and so wanted to create a symlink to that file after deployment.

After loads of research, I stumbled on appDeploy Hooks on Elastic Beanstalk that runs post scripts after deployment so did this

```
files:
  "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post/91_post_deploy_script.sh":
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      #!/usr/bin/env bash
      sudo mkdir /var/testing1
      sudo ln -sfn /var/www/html/php.conf.example /etc/nginx/conf.d/elasticbeanstalk/php.conf
      sudo mkdir /var/testing
      sudo nginx -s reload
```

And this for some reason does not work. The symlink is not created so my routes are still not working..

I even added some mkdir so am sure the commands in that script runs, none of those commands ran because none of those directories where created.

Please note that if I ssh into the ec2 instance and run the commands there it works. That bash script also exists in the post directory and if I manually run in on the server it works too.

Any pointers to how I could fix this would be helpful. Maybe I am doing something wrong too.

Now I have gotten my scripts to run by following [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html). However, the script is not running. I am getting an error

```
2020/06/28 08:22:13.653339 [INFO] Following platform hooks will be executed in order: [01_myconf.config]
2020/06/28 08:22:13.653344 [INFO] Running platform hook: .platform/hooks/postdeploy/01_myconf.config
2020/06/28 08:22:13.653516 [ERROR] An error occurred during execution of command [app-deploy] - [RunPostDeployHooks]. Stop running the command. Error: Command .platform/hooks/postdeploy/01_myconf.config failed with error fork/exec .platform/hooks/postdeploy/01_myconf.config: permission denied
```

I tried to follow this forum post [here](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=321653) to make my file executable by adding to my container command a new command like so:

```
01_chmod1:
        command: "chmod +x .platform/hooks/postdeploy/91_post_deploy_script.sh"
```

I am still running into the same issue. Permission denied

Comment: What environment is that? Amazon Linux 1 or 2?

Comment: The OS is Amazon Linux  2

Comment: What kind of hook is `appDeploy`? There is no such hook. You only [have](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html): `prebuild`, `predeploy`  and `postdeploy`?

Comment: You can make it executable on your local workstation, before zipping your application. Also when you log in into the instance, can you manually invoke the script? Does it work without any errors when run manually?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Sadly, the hooks you are describing (i.e. `/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy`) are for **Amazon Linux 1**.

Since you are using **Amazon Linux 2**, as clarified in the comments, the hooks you are trying to use do not apply. Thus they are **not being executed**.

In Amazon Linux 2, there are new hooks as described [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html) and they are:

> prebuild – Files here run after the Elastic Beanstalk platform engine downloads and extracts the application source bundle, and before it sets up and configures the application and web server.

> predeploy – Files here run after the Elastic Beanstalk platform engine sets up and configures the application and web server, and before it deploys them to their final runtime location.

> postdeploy – Files here run after the Elastic Beanstalk platform engine deploys the application and proxy server.

The use of these new hooks is **different** than in Amazon Linux 1. Thus you have to either move back to Amazon Linux 1 or migrate your application to Amazon Linux 2.

General **migration steps** from Amazon Linux 1 to Amazon Linux 2 in EB are described [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.migration-al.html)

Comment: I can see the logs now.. it is attempting to run the script but I am getting permission denied. I would assume that these scripts are running as root user. I even added sudo su in my script but its still the same error. Logs below

Running platform hook: .platform/hooks/postdeploy/01_myconf.config
2020/06/28 08:06:57.020364 [ERROR] An error occurred during execution of command [app-deploy] - [RunPostDeployHooks]. Stop running the command. Error: Command .platform/hooks/postdeploy/01_myconf.config failed with error fork/exec .platform/hooks/postdeploy/01_myconf.config: permission denied

Comment: @OmeneJosephOgheneruno Hi. `01_myconf.config` should be renamed to `01_myconf.sh`, it should be executable (chmod +x 01_myconf.sh) and also it is normal bash script. Its not enough to just re-use the same `01_myconf.config` file as you used in Amazon Linux 1. It must be rewritten for Amazon Llinux 2. I added link to the answer on how to migrate from Amazon Linux 1 to Amazon Linux 2.

Comment: this is my script now 
 sudo su <<EOF
      sudo ln -sfn /var/www/html/php.conf.example /etc/nginx/conf.d/elasticbeanstalk/php.conf
      EOF

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I would appreciate if you can offer further direction. My command is not executing.

Comment: @OmeneJosephOgheneruno Thanks. Can you update question with any error messages. Did you make your file executable?

Answer (score 0):

Create a folder called `.platform` in your project root folder and create a file with name **00_myconf.config** inside the **.platform** folder.

```
.platform/
          00_myconf.config
```

Open **00_myconf.config** and add the scripts

```
files:
  "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post/91_post_deploy_script.sh":
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      #!/usr/bin/env bash
      sudo mkdir /var/testing1
      sudo ln -sfn /var/www/html/php.conf.example /etc/nginx/conf.d/elasticbeanstalk/php.conf
      sudo mkdir /var/testing
      sudo nginx -s reload
```

Commit your changes or reupload the project. This .platform folder will be considered in each new instance creation and your application will deploy properly in all the new instances Amazon Elastic beanstalk creates.

Comment: may be the user may not have right to execute the commands. Can you check the logs and see which line of command got failed to execute

Comment: I am actually not sure of where to see logs related to this. Plus I assume there commands run as root

Comment: you can find the logs from Elastic Beanstalk environment dashboard

Comment: It is not there. I have checked several times.

Comment: @OmeneJosephOgheneruno They are there, check the left sidebar

Answer (score 0):

If you access the documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html) and scroll to the section with the title "Application example with extensions" you can see an example of the folder structure of your .platform folder so it adds your custom configuration to NGINX conf on every deploy.

You can either replace the entire nginx.conf file with your file or add additional configuration files to the conf.d directory

Replace conf file with your file on app deploy:
.platform/nginx/nginx.conf

Add configuration files to nginx.conf:
.platform/nginx/conf.d/custom.conf